# iOS app wake up by VOIP, application status wrong

Tags: ios, swift, voip

I use VOIP to wake up my app, when app receive message in

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

}
```

then applicationDidBecomeActive will be call,

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
}
```

I want to detect app is killed or not, so i add the following code like

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if application.applicationState == .background {
        // background
    } else if application.applicationState == .active {
        // active
    } else if application.applicationState == .inactive {
        // inactive
    }
}
```

But applicationState always return .active, actually the app is killed.

How can i get a right status?

Comment: If `applicationDidBecomeActive` is called then this means that the user is using your app and it can only be in the "active" state at that point. Why do you expect a different status at this point in the app lifecycle?

Comment: Because my app was killed, applicationDidBecomeActive still be call when receive VOIP message.

Comment: Please read the documentation for the `applicationDidBecomeActive` delegate method. It states *"This method is called to let your app know that it moved from the inactive to active state."*.